# Infinite tensor product definition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

My question is short and popular: how to define an infinite tensor product of modules over a ring? 
So, there is an infinite set $I$ and $A$-modules $M_i$. I should understand what $\otimes_{i\in I} M_i$ is. Could you avoid categorical terms?

Comment: Umm, how can you assert a question is popular? Shouldn't you let others be the judge of that?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11767/infinite-tensor-products  \\ http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.3128 Is easier if you take a commutative ring.

Answer (score 6):

The most obvious definition is to define a multi-linear operator on the set $\prod_{i\in I} M_i$, and the define the tensor product as a universal module with a multi-linear map from $\prod_{i\in I} M_i$. You'd have to prove that the such a universal module existed.